# Why Deprecated issues come up

Tags: wordpress

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme-child/functions.php on line 20

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; lateset_tweets has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-twitter.php on line 10

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; fb_likebox_widget has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-facebook.php on line 10

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; pulsar_video_widgets has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-video.php on line 10

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; pulsar_flickr has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-flickr.php on line 10

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; pm_mailchimp_widget has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-mailchimp.php on line 24

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; pm_ln_quickcontact_widget has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-quickcontact.php on line 24

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; pm_recentposts_widget has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-recentposts.php on line 22

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; pm_testimonials_widget has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-testimonials.php on line 22

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; pm_eventposts_widget has a deprecated constructor in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/includes/widget-events.php on line 24

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/functions.php on line 223

Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-vc-mapper.php on line 111

Notice: Undefined index: opt-invalid-security-code-error in /home/u2ot620l4yik/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vienna-theme/functions.php on line 1017

Answer (score 0):

they are there to let you know that soon those bits of code will stop working and the website will have bigger problems than 'deprecated' notices.  Make a note of where they are occurring and follow up with the theme and plugin developers to see if they have updates.  If the plugin or theme is no longer being maintained, then start looking for alternatives and put them in place before your host upgrades php.